# I can not display the info window for a polyline

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Help me please.
I can not get an infowindow
use google maps api v3.
Where is my mistake?

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "test line"
});
           downloadUrl('phpsqlinfo_addrow_lin.php', function(data) {
           var xml = data.responseXML;

           var lines = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('line');

           for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {


            var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
            var name = lines[a].getAttribute("name");
            var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));

           var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName('point');
           var pts = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
           pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute('lng')));

         }

       var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colour,
                          strokeOpacity:0.5,
                          strokeWeight:width,
                          clickable: true
                          });

       polyline.setMap(map);


       function createInfoWindow(polyline,content) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function (event) {
        infowindow.setPosition(event.LatLng);
        infowindow.setContent = content;
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
}
}  
});
```

The coordinates of the lines are selected from the base mysql.
The lines are displayed normally, and the click-through infowindow is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several typos in your code:

1. you never call the `createInfoWindow` function.
2. `setContent` is a method, not a property of the `InfoWindow`
3. `event.LatLng` should be `event.latLng`

```
function createInfoWindow(polyline, content) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function(event) {
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.setContent (content);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
createInfoWindow(polyline, "my polyline");
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ao5mktf8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 45,
      lng: -100
    },
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };
  // Display a map on the page
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var xml = xmlParse(xmlStr);
  var lines = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('line');

  for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
    var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
    var name = lines[a].getAttribute("name");
    var width = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));

    var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName('point');
    var pts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute('lng')));
    }

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: pts,
      strokeColor: colour,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: width,
      clickable: true
    });

    polyline.setMap(map);

    function createInfoWindow(polyline, content) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function(event) {
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map);
      });
    }
    createInfoWindow(polyline, "my polyline");
    google.maps.event.trigger(polyline,"click");
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function xmlParse(str) {
  if ((typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') || ("ActiveXObject" in window)) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return document.createElement('div', null);
}

var xmlStr = '<markers><line label="JBU190 rte" html="JBU190 : 03-Oct-2017 : KSAN - KJFK" colour="#00FF00" width="2"><!-- KSAN ZZOOO1 MTBAL AVRRY CADEZ HAKMN Q73 LAKRR BAWER LARVE EKR BFF FOD KG75M DAFLU J70 LVZ LENDY6 KJFK Name Latitude Longitude Outbound Course Distance this Leg Distance Remaining Distance Flown Type --><point label="KSAN" lat="32.7335556" lng="-117.1896667" Course="286" DistanceThisLeg="n/a" DistanceRemaining="2443" DistanceFlown="0" Type="KSAN Origin Airport" /><point label="JETTI" lat="32.7546111" lng="-117.2765278" Course="168" DistanceThisLeg="5" DistanceRemaining="2447" DistanceFlown="5" Type="JETTI Waypoint" /><point label="ZZOOO" lat="32.6314444" lng="-117.2458333" Course="96" DistanceThisLeg="9" DistanceRemaining="2449" DistanceFlown="8" Type="ZZOOO Waypoint" /><point label="JORRJ" lat="32.6018333" lng="-116.9161389" Course="77" DistanceThisLeg="19" DistanceRemaining="2433" DistanceFlown="18" Type="JORRJ Waypoint" /><point label="GRIDR" lat="32.6302222" lng="-116.7731944" Course="22" DistanceThisLeg="9" DistanceRemaining="2425" DistanceFlown="25" Type="GRIDR Waypoint" /><point label="PIEZZ" lat="33.0094167" lng="-116.5874444" Course="24" DistanceThisLeg="28" DistanceRemaining="2404" DistanceFlown="40" Type="PIEZZ Waypoint" /><point label="NSHEE" lat="33.3993611" lng="-116.3831111" Course="54" DistanceThisLeg="29" DistanceRemaining="2381" DistanceFlown="66" Type="NSHEE Waypoint" /><point label="MTBAL" lat="33.6033056" lng="-116.0423056" Course="69" DistanceThisLeg="24" DistanceRemaining="2358" DistanceFlown="90" Type="MTBAL Waypoint" /><point label="AVRRY" lat="33.7520417" lng="-115.5707111" Course="23" DistanceThisLeg="29" DistanceRemaining="2329" DistanceFlown="117" Type="AVRRY Waypoint (RNAV)" /><point label="CADEZ" lat="34.2065639" lng="-115.3428722" Course="9" DistanceThisLeg="34" DistanceRemaining="2304" DistanceFlown="147" Type="CADEZ Reporting Point" /><point label="HAKMN" lat="35.5078639" lng="-115.0797333" Course="48" DistanceThisLeg="91" DistanceRemaining="2256" DistanceFlown="227" Type="HAKMN RNAV" /><point label="ZZYZX" lat="35.6648667" lng="-114.8652750" Course="48" DistanceThisLeg="16" DistanceRemaining="2240" DistanceFlown="242" Type="ZZYZX RNAV" />\<point label="LAKRR" lat="36.0854778" lng="-114.2858778" Course="45" DistanceThisLeg="44" DistanceRemaining="2200" DistanceFlown="285" Type="LAKRR RNAV" /><point label="BAWER" lat="37.6351889" lng="-112.2794139" Course="52" DistanceThisLeg="154" DistanceRemaining="2059" DistanceFlown="438" Type="BAWER Waypoint (RNAV)" /><point label="LARVE" lat="39.0479694" lng="-109.9432306" Course="56" DistanceThisLeg="160" DistanceRemaining="1910" DistanceFlown="596" Type="LARVE Waypoint (RNAV)" /><point label="EKR" lat="40.0675000" lng="-107.9250000" Course="60" DistanceThisLeg="129" DistanceRemaining="1789" DistanceFlown="723" Type="EKR VOR-DME (NAVAID)" /><point label="BFF" lat="41.8941667" lng="-103.4819444" Course="81" DistanceThisLeg="264" DistanceRemaining="1539" DistanceFlown="983" Type="BFF VOR-TAC (NAVAID)" /><point label="FOD" lat="42.6111111" lng="-94.2947222" Course="89" DistanceThisLeg="473" DistanceRemaining="1067" DistanceFlown="1421" Type="FOD VOR-TAC (NAVAID)" /><point label="KG75M" lat="42.5000000" lng="-88.0000000" Course="90" DistanceThisLeg="321" DistanceRemaining="746" DistanceFlown="1725" Type="KG75M NRS-WAYPOINT" /><point label="DAFLU" lat="42.3790833" lng="-82.6887778" Course="93" DistanceThisLeg="271" DistanceRemaining="477" DistanceFlown="1990" Type="DAFLU Reporting Point" /><point label="BROKK" lat="42.3313889" lng="-81.5819389" Course="94" DistanceThisLeg="57" DistanceRemaining="421" DistanceFlown="2045" Type="BROKK Reporting Point" /><point label="BEWEL" lat="42.2898583" lng="-80.7619278" Course="94" DistanceThisLeg="42" DistanceRemaining="379" DistanceFlown="2087" Type="BEWEL Reporting Point" /><point label="JHW" lat="42.1886075" lng="-79.1213050" Course="109" DistanceThisLeg="84" DistanceRemaining="297" DistanceFlown="2170" Type="JHW VOR-DME (NAVAID)" /><point label="HOXIE" lat="41.8650111" lng="-77.8526056" Course="109" DistanceThisLeg="69" DistanceRemaining="228" DistanceFlown="2233" Type="HOXIE Reporting Point" /><point label="DMACK" lat="41.7857583" lng="-77.5519222" Course="110" DistanceThisLeg="16" DistanceRemaining="212" DistanceFlown="2248" Type="DMACK Reporting Point" />\<point label="STENT" lat="41.6790472" lng="-77.1527556" Course="110" DistanceThisLeg="22" DistanceRemaining="190" DistanceFlown="2269" Type="STENT Reporting Point" /><point label="MAGIO" lat="41.5273833" lng="-76.5964944" Course="110" DistanceThisLeg="31" DistanceRemaining="159" DistanceFlown="2297" Type="MAGIO Reporting Point" /><point label="LVZ" lat="41.2728025" lng="-75.6894678" Course="313" DistanceThisLeg="50" DistanceRemaining="109" DistanceFlown="2343" Type="LVZ VOR-TAC (NAVAID)" /><point label="LVZ" lat="41.2728056" lng="-75.6894722" Course="114" DistanceThisLeg="0" DistanceRemaining="109" DistanceFlown="2343" Type="LVZ VOR-TAC (NAVAID)" /><point label="JENNO" lat="41.1529167" lng="-75.3314167" Course="114" DistanceThisLeg="20" DistanceRemaining="89" DistanceFlown="2362" Type="JENNO Reporting Point" /><point label="HARTY" lat="41.0711944" lng="-75.0898889" Course="114" DistanceThisLeg="14" DistanceRemaining="75" DistanceFlown="2375" Type="HARTY Reporting Point" /><point label="MUGZY" lat="41.0301389" lng="-74.9693611" Course="114" DistanceThisLeg="7" DistanceRemaining="68" DistanceFlown="2381" Type="MUGZY Reporting Point" /><point label="STW" lat="40.9958333" lng="-74.8690278" Course="98" DistanceThisLeg="6" DistanceRemaining="62" DistanceFlown="2386" Type="STW VOR-DME (NAVAID)" /><point label="LENDY" lat="40.9148333" lng="-74.1352500" Course="123" DistanceThisLeg="39" DistanceRemaining="27" DistanceFlown="2424" Type="LENDY Reporting Point" /><point label="LGA" lat="40.7837222" lng="-73.8686111" Course="155" DistanceThisLeg="17" DistanceRemaining="11" DistanceFlown="2438" Type="LGA VOR-DME (NAVAID)" /><point label="KJFK" lat="40.6399257" lng="-73.7786950" Course="n/" DistanceThisLeg="11" DistanceRemaining="0" DistanceFlown="2443" Type="KJFK Destination Airport" />  </line></markers>'
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id='map_canvas'></div>
```